# Didn't work on a 1440P 144hz monitor & crash during installation

Tags: system-installation

Here is my situation.
My PC is X570(MSI)+3700X+2070S.
My monitor is 1440P 144HZ.

At first, I couldn't start the installation. Then I changed my monitor to hdmi1.4. The refresh rate was set to 60HZ.
After that, I started the installation and crash two times during the installation. I'm not sure I should try the third time.
Can anything help me out? with the refresh rate and the crash
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This sort of crash is typically due to the fact that proprietary NVidia drivers are missing during installation. I would install Ubuntu with `nomodeset` which tells it to not load any incompatible video drivers. To do that

1. Insert the Ubuntu 19.04 or 18.04 USB into the computer.
2. Reboot.
3. As soon as it boots, press up or down arrow on your keyboard to bring up the Grub menu, then select English.
4. At the Grub Menu, press <kbd>F6</kbd> and scroll down to where it says `nomodeset`.[image].
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> so there is an `X` next to it, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the menu.
6. Then proceed to install Ubuntu.

After Ubuntu is fully installed, then you can install the driver for your card. As far as I understand, the RTX 2070 super is supported in NVidia drivers 430+. To install it, run the following command.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && sudo reboot
```